# Pandas - math operation on H:M:S string format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, math

I have some time data that I need to subtract the largest value (last row) from the smallest value (first row) per month. The `HOURS` column is a in string (object) format though, and I don't know how to convert this properly and then get it back into the current format. The end result needs to be displayed as `H:M:S`. The data looks as follows:

```
MACHINE HOURS       MONTH

M400    54:56:00    December
M400    61:54:52    December
M400    75:38:52    December
M400    89:21:09    December
M400    13:44:00    November
M400    27:28:00    November
M400    41:12:00    November
```

The end result I'm looking for is:

```
MACHINE HOURS       MONTH

M400    34:25:09    December
M400    27:28:00    November
```

What is the fastest way to convert this (I'm assuming to datetime format), do the math, then reverse back?

Comment: you can also use regex to extract H, M, S and convert the whole into seconds. Then perform your operation

Comment: convert the column to timedelta: `df['HOURS'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['HOURS'])` and you can do arithmetic operations (sum, mean, etc...)

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of to achieve this is, although there might be more efficient way.

```py
def convert(h):
    #convert string to seconds
    h = h.split(':')
    h = list(map(int, h))
    return h[0]*3600+h[1]*60+h[2]

def convert_back(t):
    #convert seconds to string
    m,s = divmod(t,60)
    h,m = divmod(m,60)
    return f"{h}:{m}:{s}"

df['time'] = df['hours'].apply(convert)

final = (df.groupby('month').max()['time'] - df.groupby('month').min()['time']).apply(convert_back)

df_final = df.groupby('month').max()
df_final['hours'] = final
```

`df_final` is what you are looking for.